# C++ Overloading operator << for child classes

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have created a class `Location` which is a parent class for classes `Village` and `City`. I have a `vector<Location*>`, which contains villages and cities. Now, I need to print to the standard output the content of this `vector`. This is easy:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < locations.size(); i++)
       cout << locations.at(i);
```

I have overloaded operator << for classes `Village`, `City` and `Location`. It is called overloaded operator << from class `Location` all the time. I need to call overloaded operator for `Village` and `City` (depends on specific instance). Is there something similar like virtual methods for overloading operators?

I'm new in programming in C++, I'm programming in Java, so please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely you mean `vector<Location*>`, because otherwise I assure you that it doesn't contain villages and cities.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, you're right, sorry.

Comment: Please show the signatures of the operators; are they member functions or global functions?

Comment: In the base class create a virtual method for output. This function should be overrided by derived classes and be delegated to in the implementation of `operator<<()`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer**

No, there is no such thing. You can use existing C++ features to emulate it.

**Long answer**

You can add a method to Location `virtual void Print(ostream& os)` and implement `operator<<` like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Location& loc) 
{ 
    loc.Print(os); 
    return os; 
}
```

If you override `Print()` in your derived classes you will get your desired functionality.

Comment: And then I have to call print() method in my `for` loop?

Comment: @PSglass No, you call `operator<<()`.

Comment: Simply like this: `cout << locations.at(i);`?. If yes, I tried it and it prints addresses of objects.

Answer (score 4):

Since `operator<<` can't be a member function (without changing its semantics), you could provide a virtual `print` method and do double dispatch..

```
class Location
{
  virtual void print (ostream&);
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& o, Location& l)
{
  l.print(o); // virtual call
  return o;
}
```